# Why is my onChange event not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using a onchange event to copy the current span's text to the hidden field. Why is my onchange event not working? http://jsfiddle.net/Hunter4854/qfdvE/

Comment: Copy the concerned code here. What if jsfiddle dies tomorrow? This question won't make any sense. Besides, the code on jsfiddle is *very* long.

Comment: you're applying a `change` event to a `span`? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp

Comment: You seriously need to post your code *here*, not just a link to another site.

Answer (score 2):

`innerText` is not a jQuery method; use `text`.  Also, you're going backwards, assigning the content of the hidden to the span.  So instead of this:

```
$('#span').innerText($('#dropdown').val());
```

do this:

```
$('#dropdown').val($('#span').text());
```

Comment: That does not change the value of the hidden input. Also, i used the first one and second one and they are not working.

Comment: The "first one" is your code; that won't work.  The second block of code will work, but not inside of a `change` event handler for a `span`; spans do not raise events when they change.  Run this code whenever you know the span's contents will change.

Comment: what can i use besides a span? Can you help me fix the problem?

Comment: You're fine using a span; It looks like it's your own code that changes the span (specifically the line where you do `$(this).find('span').html($tgt.html());`.  You can just populate your hidden input after running that line.

Comment: I still do not understand. Can you make a befuddle for me to see.

Comment: I just wanted to copy the text in the span to a hidden field, so that I can use php to get their choice.

Comment: The easiest thing to do then would be to run the code to copy the content into the hidden *just before* the form data is sent back to the server.

Comment: Is there any other option ... like using something.besides the span...so it cam work